Edit Excel cells immediately upon opening file
Excel 2019 on Mac.
Whenever I open an excel file, I have to click a cell before I can start editing it, even though a cell is already selected. Typing, arrow keys, enter key, etc. do not work either. The only key that works is Tab which, after several Tabs in my case, will finally reach cell A2 and I can start entering data.
I want to be able to immediately start entering data (with a barcode scanner) in cell A2 upon opening the file, without having to manually click on cell A2 or press the Tab key.
The Excel file itself is opened automatically as part of an Automator workflow, but the same applies if I open any random Excel file manually.
Cell A2 looks like and IS selected, but I cannot edit it until I single click on it.

I have tried running the following AppleScript (the switch between sheets was just to see if it would do anything) as part of the Automator workflow, but have had no success:
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        select sheet "Sheet2"
        select sheet "Sheet1"
        select cell "A2"
        
        
    end tell
    
end run

I am open to solutions with either AppleScript, Excel VBA, Automator or any settings that might be causing this.
Using the mouseclick on AppleScript is not a viable solution in my opinion, as it clicks at specific coordinates, which might change if the Excel file has moved slightly upon opening.
A solution using the Tab key would also not be ideal, as the number of tabs necessary might change if the number of warnings (yellow) ribbon also changes.
To summarize, I would like to be able to do the following:

Open Excel file (automatically through Automator)
select cell A2 (without having to physically single click on it)
start entering data through barcode scanner.

I have spent a considerable amount of time researching this issue so far, so I would really appreciate some help.

This sounds more like an excel settings issue. Maybe something like 'allow editing directly in cell' — link. Another potential issue… you may have some data entry restriction, eg enter value from list. What happens if you use a clean spreadsheet based on a clean template (ie what you would get immediately after a fresh install).

@Mockman I did try all of these steps initially but, unfortunately, cannot seem to figure out what is causing this. Settings do not change anything, no matter if editing directly in cell is allowed or not. Clean spreadsheets also have the same issue. Some of my colleagues' computers also have the same issue and we cannot find the difference in setup/settings.

Then I'd suggest a support call to whoever supports the software. Needing to script access to a cell isn't normal. Is there any protection on the cells?

@Mockman I suppose that means calling Microsoft? There is no protection of any kind, the same thing happens to every workbook I open. If I have the volume turned up, you can even hear the error sound every time I press any key that is not the TAB key. Everything works fine as soon as I click somewhere inside the sheet on any of the cells.

Did you install excel yourself? Or is it deployed by an IT department? What happens if you open a csv file in excel? Is it similarly afflicted? Or if you save a spreadsheet as an older (eg '97 or '04) file format. Or get someone to send you a spreadsheet that doesn't have this problem on their computer and see what happens. Maybe quit the app and then trash the preferences. Maybe re-run the 'first run' tool.

BTW, to answer your applescript question, this line should open up the active cell for editing directly: tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Microsoft Excel" to key code 32 using control down. Place it immediately below the select cell "A2" line. Key code 32 specifies the 'u' key on a US English keyboard; ctrl-u is the shortcut for 'Edit the active cell'. It is the mac equivalent of 'F2' on windows. The insertion point will be set at the end of any existing text in the cell.

Also, you might ask a question about excel (sans applescript) on the superuser site. There are a lot of excel experts there. They may ask you to upload a sample spreadsheet.

@Mockman sorry for the late response, but I finally managed to solve this in the most ridiculous way...If you look at my screenshot, you will see a yellow "office update" bar. That is what was causing the problem. Getting rid of the update prompt fixed my issue. Now every spreadsheet I open automatically focuses on a given cell inside it, as it should by default. I am just praying that the bar does not come back at some point, especially when the barcode scanner employees are in the middle of their work...

That's quite the culprit. Glad the mystery is solved.
